# Passing parameters to current imported class

Tags: reactjs

I am using grommet.io for ui. Now I have handled ui but I want to pass data to a function to make a modal, so I want to pass an id or other parameters.

I passed it by using heading={heading} but I can't read it with alert

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Box from "grommet/components/Box";
import Card from "grommet/components/Card";

import Layer from 'grommet/components/Layer';

class Note extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.showCardDetails = this.showCardDetails.bind(this)
  }

  showCardDetails = (e) => {
    alert( (e.target.heading)  )
  }

  render() {
    const { heading, description } = this.props
    return (
      <Box flex={true} direction='row' justify='center' align='center' wrap={true} pad='small' margin='small' colorIndex='accent-1' value={heading} onFocus=''>
        <Card heading={heading}
          description={description}
          textSize='medium' onClick={this.showCardDetails} contentPad='none' size='small' onFocus='' />
      </Box>
    )
  }
}



export default Note;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `showCardDetails` is `Note` method, its props are available there, as they are in `render`:

```
  showCardDetails = (e) => {
    const { heading, description } = this.props;
    alert(heading);
  }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know and practice. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Say for example you want to get id and value of the card so you need to pass id and value as params to the event handler function so that you can get those values when card clicked.

or also say when you are rendering cards in loop and to get the id of particular card clicked then below is the way to get the values of that particular card

To get id and value you need to id value directly to method as params and access the params in method

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Box from "grommet/components/Box";
import Card from "grommet/components/Card";

import Layer from 'grommet/components/Layer';

class Note extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.showCardDetails = this.showCardDetails.bind(this)
  }

  showCardDetails = (id, heading) => {
    alert(id, heading)
  }

  render() {
    const { heading, description, id} = this.props
    return (
      <Box flex={true} direction='row' justify='center' align='center' wrap={true} pad='small' margin='small' colorIndex='accent-1' value={heading} onFocus=''>
        <Card description={description}
          textSize='medium' onClick={() => this.showCardDetails(id, heading)} contentPad='none' size='small' onFocus='' />
      </Box>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the working solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/grommet-pro-fgjnsb?file=Note.js

Comment: @tarekhassan I have updated my answer please have a look